# Доработать хайлатер google реально?

Tags: javascript

У гугла есть хайлатер кода: https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Вот так он подсвечивает код:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<pre class="prettyprint">function getCode($elem) {
 var source = $($elem)
      .clone()
      .html(),
  lines = source.split("\n"),

 // kill empty lines at start/end
 while (lines.length > 0 && $.trim(lines[0]) === "") {
  lines.shift();
 }

 var tabAtStart = /^\t/g;
 while (lines[0].search(tabAtStart) > -1) {
  $.each(lines, function (index, value) {
   lines[index] = value.replace(tabAtStart, "");
  });
 }}</pre>
```

Убогая подсветка потому что `getCode` и `($elem)` отображаются одним цветом, `lines` и `[index]` внутри него тоже. То же самое у `highlighter.js`

Что я хочу есть у *prismjs* но там нет автоопределния языка...

**Вопрос**: по какому принципу строится хайлатер? Понятно что итоговый файл отвечающий за подсветку это `https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/js-modules/prettify.js` но что и где в нём поменять что бы внести нужные изменения? JS знаю, но наверное не на таком уровне что бы писать свой хайлатер ))

Comment: Подсветка стилизуется разметкой и CSS

Comment: Ай хэв квешен к Вам: что такое "хайлатер"?

Comment: @edem, подсвечивательщик